# Автоматическое преобразование последовательного кода в многопоточный

Tags: многопоточность, любой-язык

В каких языках программирования реализовано автоматическое преобразование последовательного кода в многопоточный ([Automatic parallelization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_parallelization))?

Comment: Хм, мб, Фортран?

Comment: Судя по вики, это что-то математическое и низкоуровневое. Вам зачем?